# How to make a graph change color based on value

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a graph change color based on value. Here is my
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLwxW.png). I put the formula =IF(L89 <= L104 ,L89, NA()) in all the part of the data to the right, obviously changing the cell references appropriately. This gave me this [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um4Kg.png). I then went to series options then changed series overlap to 100%. This gave me [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXgTs.png). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Series overlap makes all the bars at the category point to come "closer", with 100% they comes "together" .. Try 60 or 70 % if you want them closer not together.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the overlap to 100% you essentially put bars behind each other, hence some bars that have the same (or a very similar) value are no longer visible. What you might want to do, instead of changing the series overlap to 100%, is creating a s[tacked bar chart](https://www.smartsheet.com/stacked-bar-chart-graph).

Answer (score 0):

You could have two series - one set to zero and the other showing values in a colour.

Then, using if() change the series with values to zero and put values on the series in the other colour - just need to control the cells with the correct data

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Well, have one cell with data valudation that you change from A to B or 1 to 2. Then use if() to choose the value or 0 depending which series you want to see.